# How are Scala closures implemented in Scala.NET?

Tags: .net, scala, closures, anonymous-class

As I understand it, Function types in Scala compile to instances of *FunctionN*. So that for example this example

```
List(1,2,3).filter(_ >= 2)
```

means

```
List(1,2,3).filter(new Function1[Int,Bool]{def apply(_$1:Int) = _$1 >= 2;})
```

How is this implemented in Scala.NET? As I understand it, .NET does not have statement-level anonymous classes. And the above solution depends on there being anonymous classes.

Comment: But they can't implement interfaces right? So they don't really help in this case?

Comment: @Heandel, there are anonymous types in **C#**, but they don't have anything to do with this.

Comment: No idea, but there are no anonymous classes in Java bytecode either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about Scala, but I don't see why that shouldn't be implemented the same way as C# closures, i.e. the following code:

```
new List<int>{1,2,3}.Where(i => i >= 2)
```

This code is implemented by creating a new function in the current class. If you really created a closure:

```
int max = 2;
var result = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.Where(i => i >= max);
```

That would be implemented by creating a new class that contains the variable `max` along with the anonymous function.

**EDIT:**

I just tried compiling your code using Scala.Net and looking at the compiled code in Reflector gives this:

```
int[] numArray1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
List$.MODULE$.apply(new BoxedIntArray(numArray1)).filter(new $anonfun$1());
```

Where `$anonfun$1` is a class that implements the `Function1` interface and its `apply()` function looks like this:

```
public sealed override bool apply(int x$1)
{
    return (x$1 >= 2);
}
```